# Knowing when a MFMailComposeViewController is gone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is there a way to know when a MFMailComposeViewController is dismissed?

The controller vanishes automatically when the email is sent.

I have tried to use mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error: but when this method is triggered the controller is still visible.

I have tried to add a viewWillDisappear method but MFMailComposeViewController is not triggering that.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Here You van Get CallBack as MailComposer Has Dissmissed");
 //So do whatever you want......
}];
}
```

This Method is called Whenever the `Cancel,save or Send` mail Button clicked.
From Apple DOC:-

Your implementation of this method should dismiss the mail composition view. Implementation of this method is optional but expected.

If the user has opted to send the email created by this interface, that email should be queued in the user’s Mail program by the time this method is called. If an error occurred while queueing the email message, the error parameter contains an error object indicating the type of failure that occurred.

[See The Detailed Information](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: DUUUHHH! I missed that! I knew the answer was before my eyes but I could not see... T H A N K S !!!!!!!!

Comment: @RubberDuck u welcome,it happens .....Enjoy.Same Thing Had Happened Many times with me...